# Python Requests POST is not uploading images

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I'm trying to make a script that will auto-upload images that I place in a folder on my PC, but I'm having trouble getting my `POST` request to work.

Here is the form I'm trying to submit to...

```
<form method="POST" action="/uploadeventthumb.php?id=0" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image"><p>
    <input type="hidden" name="id2" value="3kkggi1618601391"></p><p>
    <input type="hidden" name="id3" value="1113887"></p><p>
    <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
    <br></p><p>Please only upload JPG images. <br>The dimensions should be <b>1280x720</b> pixels Wide and High.
    </p></form>
```

Here is my code...

```
for f in glob.glob(upload+'*-t.jpg'):
    f = f.replace("\\", "/")
    sessionObj = requests.session()
    r = sessionObj.post(TheSportsDB.login, TheSportsDB.login_data)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print("Logged in!")
    file = {'file' : open(f, 'rb')}
    fn = f.replace(upload, "")
    fn = fn.replace("-t.jpg", "")
    TSDB = TheSportsDB.thumb+fn
    r = sessionObj.post(TSDB, files=file)
    print(r.text)
```

When I run the script I get a successful `Logged in!` message and then it prints out the text from the upload page, but never actually uploads the image, can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong, please!

Comment: Why do you ignore id1 and id2 form fields?

Comment: @NobbyNobbs They already have values to be submitted.

Comment: What do you mean "they already have values"? There is nothing about them in your code. `requests` client does nothing with html it fetch, it's just a client, not a web-browser. You should extract all the hidden fields from html form, and pass them manually in you post request alongside with the file, and also don't forget about id0 (the query parameter). Probably they're used as csrf-tokens, or some staff like that.

Comment: @NobbyNobbs So are you saying that I need to obtain the "3kkggi1618601391" and "1113887" values first and then ```post``` using those too?

Comment: Yes. You should totally mimic the form, all the fields, path, query params, everything.

Comment: Thank you for your help @NobbyNobbs, I'll try a few things with that.

Answer (score 0):

What I was intending to use this script for just wasn't possible as the id2 field changed on every request, so I'm guessing it is a CSRF token as mentioned by @NobbyNobbs in the comments.

I managed to easily create the script using Selenium rather than Requests and BeautifulSoup.